# Does pipe.transform(obj, arg1,arg2) call by reference and what does it do in html?

Tags: angular

I am quite new to the TypeScript/JS thing, I read that JS passes parameters by value as long as they are not objects or arrays.

I have a few questions with the reference of the object passed into the pipe. Lets say I call `pipe.transform(obj, size)` in my Component Class, and the pipe implements something like

```
obj.filter(item => item.getIndex() > size);
return obj;
```

That would cut the array down to a smaller array, now lets say I call it again with a bigger size paramter, the pipe will work with the already filtered array, since JS calls parameters of type array by reference. What would I need to do to invoke the `.transform()` function with the initial array all the time?

And whes using the pipe in the HTML file, with `"array | pipe: size"`, is the array called by reference or by value there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> JS passes parameters by value as long as they are not objects or arrays.

No. JS passes parameters by value. Whatever the type is. It doesn't pass objects or arrays, but references to objects or arrays. And these references are passed by value.

> That would cut the array down to a smaller array

No. `filter()` doesn't modify the array. It creates a filtered copy of the array. So your pipe doesn't do anything. It returns the array unmodified.